# impossible to retrieve the values of my form php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

/********Actualisation de la session...**********/

include('../includes/fonctions.php');
connexionbdd();
actualiser_session();

/********Fin actualisation de session...**********/

 if(!isset($_SESSION['membre_admin']))  {
  header ('Location: index.php');
  exit();

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<script language="javascript">

            function confirmeee( identifiant )
              {
                var confirmation = confirm( "Voulez vous vraiment éditercet enregistrement ?" ) ;
        if( confirmation )
        {
          document.location = "edition1.php?idNews="+identifiant ;
        }
        else(confirmation)
            {
                alert("erreur");
            }
          }

    </script>
...
```

and my form

```
<?php

  //récupération de la variable d'URL,
  //qui va nous permettre de savoir quel enregistrement éditer:
  $id  = $_GET["idNews"] ;

  //requête SQL:
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM news
        WHERE id = ".$id ;
    $requete=mysql_query($sql);
  //echo "$sql" ;       
  //exécution de la requête:
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $requete ))
    {

      if($row["text"] != NULL)
        {
           echo '<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirmeee('.$row["id"].')">
           <tr><td>Id article : '.$row["id"].'</label></td></br></br>
           <tr><td><label for="textarea" class="float">Titre :</label></td>

            <td><TEXTAREA name="title"  cols="90" >'.$row["title"].'</TEXTAREA></td></tr></br></br>
            <tr><td><label for="title" class="float">Contenu :</label></td>

            <td><TEXTAREA name="text" WRAP=VIRTUAL rows="30" cols="100" >'.$row["text"].'</TEXTAREA></td></tr></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Mise à jour"  ></br></br>
            </form>';
        }
    }

?>
```

and my page **edition1.php** which it is impossible to retrieve information :

```
<?php

  $id  = $_GET["idNews"] ;


      //récupération du formulaire
      $text=formulaires($_POST['text']);
      $title=formulaires($_POST['title']);
      $text = nl2br($text); 

      mysql_query("UPDATE news SET text='$text' , title='$title' WHERE id='".$_GET['idNews']."' ") or die ('Erreur : '.mysql_error());
      echo'L\'article a été modifié<br/><a href="admin.php">Retour</a></br>';


?>
```

I can t retrieve the informations in **edition1.php**, when i try my update, this remove my data in **"text"** and **"title"**.

where is my mistake?

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_* API!!

Comment: `else(confirmation)` is a SyntaxError in JavaScript — it should be just `else`. You don’t even need the variable. Just write `if(confirm(`…`))`.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help! I made the changes that you told me , but now the submit not even sent me in edition1.php :x

Answer (score 0):

I would change the form tag :

```
<form method="post" action="edition1.php?idNews='.$row["id"].'">
```

Then put an onclick event on the button with your JS function :

```
<input type="submit" value="Mise à jour" onClick="confirmeee()"  />
```

You don't need the id in the JS script anymore.

Then finally call

```
this.form.submit()
```

instead of

```
document.location = "edition1.php?idNews="+identifiant ;
```

Comment: everything works , I thank you 1 billion times !!!!!! :D I 'm on it since yesterday!!!